# Handle exception in Node.js and send the error output to HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, express

I have a function which console logs the error in case error exist, I wish to send the same data back to HTML `<div>`. The `<div>` must only load in case of error and present user with the error msg.

*app.js*

```
console.log('Pulling Image from DockerHub\n');
const result1 = cp.execSync('docker pull mongo:'+version);
console.log(result1.toString());
```

Let's say the above code generates an error and I wish to get the data on my HTML using jQuery AJAX.

*index.html*

```
<div id="errorReport"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){     
            $.ajax({
                    url: "http://localhost:8090/api/route1",
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType:'json', 
                    success: function(res) {
                        console.log(res);
                    }
                });    
            });                   
</script>
```

Need to handle error exceptions in the above child process `(app.js)` and render the data on `index.html` ONLY if ERROR exists. If the cp doesn't return any error, no need to render any data on `index.html`

**Update:**
Let's say in here `const result1 = cp.execSync('docker pull mongo:'+version);` I give an incorrect value for version and the child process fails. As per the `execSync` syntax I cannot have a callback function to determine the error.

Now the console does display some error msg

```
Error response from daemon: manifest for mongo:a not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown
child_process.js:660
    throw err;
    ^
```

Now if I wish to display the same msg on my HMTL `<div>` what do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to `catch` the error on the server and return it in the HTTP response. You don't have to use `.json({ ... })`, but it tends to be convenient.

```
try {
  cp.execSync(`docker pull mongo:'+version`);
  res.status(200)
} catch (error) {
  // catch the error and return it's message to the client
  res.status(500).json({ error: error.message })
}
```

`error.message` tends to have the type of message you describe, but you can also access other fields like the stack trace, etc. Since the server is returning a statusCode 500, that will trigger the `error` callback, so you will need to add that handler to your request, then add the message to the DOM.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:8090/api/route1",
    type: 'POST',
    dataType:'json', 
    success: function(res) {
        console.log(res);
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      // parse the JSON from the server
      const json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
      // finally, set the div's text to the error
      $("#errorReport").text(json.error);
    }
  });    
});
```

Comment: Could you do me me another favour? I have a table `<table id="tab1"></table>` I'd like to hide it in case an error occurs and the error function executes. Tried including `$("#table1").hide();` inside error function but it doesn't seem to work this way.

Comment: Hm, I would expect `.hide()` to work. I notice your id is `tab1`, but you typed `#table1` in the comment, perhaps that's the source of the problem?

Comment: A typo error id is in fact table1 in both cases, although I have AJAX complete function where I have declared `$("#table1").show();` is that why I still see the table even if error exists?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this -

```
<div id="errorReport"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){    
            $("#errorReport").hide();
            $.ajax({
                    url: "http://localhost:8090/api/route1",
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType:'json', 
                    success: function(res, status) {
                        if(status === 500){
                           $("#errorReport").show();
                        }
                        console.log(res);
                    }
                });    
            });                   
</script>
```

On your server -

```
try {
  cp.execSync(`docker pull mongo:'+version`);
  res.status(200)
 } catch (error) {
  //catch the error here and handle it accordingly by sending error response to client
 res.status(500)
 }
```

Comment: Also, consider using the new `fetch` API available in vanilla JS, instead of **$.ajax**

Comment: Additionally, you can display the err inside the `div` , use `$("#errorReport").text(Error occured! ' + err');`, a line before `$("#errorReport").show();`

Comment: So by adding error function to my ajax call does help to some extent. However, I wish to display the console error message inside my html `<div>` now it simple displays Error msg with [object][object].

Comment: I have added few more details in my question. Also, `execSync()` is inside a callback function so most likely the error retuned from my Node.js API is not even for for `execSync`.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the `execSync` in try catch block ? See the updated answer.

Comment: yes, the whole callback function and `execSync` is inside a try block. Followed by     `catch(e) 
    {
        console.error('Error Occured', e);
    }`

Comment: Please check the updated answer, if this helps. Also, I am unclear about how to get response status in AJAX. Please verify

Comment: Yeah sure let me check